# compare a datetime column only to time in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a df like below

```
col1, mydate
1, 25-DEC-2016 09:15:00
2, 25-DEC-2016 10:14:00
3, 25-DEC-2016 10:16:00
4, 25-DEC-2016 10:18:56
2, 25-DEC-2016 11:14:00
2, 25-DEC-2016 10:16:00

df.info(): mydate    323809 non-null object
```

I need to this dataframe according to time, like df having time less than 10:15:00, df having time less than 11:15:00

So created my slice intervals using

```
times=[pd.to_datetime(i) for i in '10:15:00','11:15:00','12:15:00','13:15:00','14:15:00','15:15:00', '15:30:00']
```

Then I convert my mydate type to time
which takes a lot of time

```
df['mydate']=df4.mydate.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x,infer_datetime_format=True).time())
```

The above command I think can be optimised, or there should be a better/faster way.

Then I simply do

```
for time in times:
  slice = df[df.mydate<time.time()]
```

My intent is only to compare df.mydate time with `['10:15:00','11:15:00','12:15:00','13:15:00','14:15:00','15:15:00', '15:30:00']` **(but not dates)** and simply subset df

The above way works fine for me but I am looking for a better way.

Additional:
Interestingly sorting mydate was very fast (even though I did not convert to mydate col to datetime) using

```
df.sort_values(by='mydate')
```

which lets me think that my way of subsetting should be faster.

mydate col will always be in `25-DEC-2016 09:15:00` format (Note DEC not Dec) can I use `format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: Why not just use lambda function to get time substring and then just use string comparison will do. I think time conversion will cost time. Reduce conversion time will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `timedelta` is better for working in pandas - so first [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) string column and select times for converting:

```
df['mydate'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['mydate'].str.split().str[1])
print (df)
   col1   mydate
0     1 09:15:00
1     2 10:14:00
2     3 10:16:00
3     4 10:18:56
4     2 11:14:00
5     2 10:16:00
```

Convert `list` too:

```
times=pd.to_timedelta(['10:15:00','11:15:00','12:15:00',
                       '13:15:00','14:15:00','15:15:00', '15:30:00'])
print (times)
TimedeltaIndex(['10:15:00', '11:15:00', '12:15:00', '13:15:00', '14:15:00',
                '15:15:00', '15:30:00'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Last create slices:

```
for time in times:
  sl = df[df.mydate<time]
  print (sl)
```

Comment: Thanks. As an additional doubt, I want to know how `df.sort_values(by='mydate')` could sort values (without any type conversion). Is this a good way to sort this way?

Answer (score 7):

First of all, I suggest using `pd.to_datetime` on the whole array/Series, so it would be:

```
pd.to_datetime(['10:15:00','11:15:00','12:15:00','13:15:00']).time
```

Rather than

```
[pd.to_datetime(i).time() for i in ['10:15:00','11:15:00','12:15:00','13:15:00']]
```

Secondly, you are right about the format. As stated in the documentation of [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) it is much faster (by x5-10 times) to use

```
pd.to_datetime(['25-DEC-2016 09:15:00', '25-DEC-2016 09:15:00'],
               format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Rather than

```
pd.to_datetime(['25-DEC-2016 09:15:00', '26-DEC-2016 09:15:00'], 
               infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Considering now your dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 2], 
                   'mydate': ['25-DEC-2016 09:15:00',
                              '25-DEC-2016 11:15:00', 
                              '26-DEC-2016 11:15:00', 
                              '26-DEC-2016 12:15:00']})
>>>
   col1                mydate
0     1  25-DEC-2016 09:15:00
1     2  25-DEC-2016 11:15:00
2     3  26-DEC-2016 11:15:00
3     2  26-DEC-2016 12:15:00
```

You can first transform the `mydate` column in an actual `datetime` Series:

```
df['mydate'] = pd.to_datetime(df.mydate, format='%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Then you'll be able to access the `date` and `time` fields (and a lot more) through the `dt` accessor:

```
df.mydate.dt.date
>>>
0    2016-12-25
1    2016-12-25
2    2016-12-26
3    2016-12-26

df.mydate.dt.time
>>>
0    09:15:00
1    11:15:00
2    11:15:00
3    12:15:00
```

So when computing the slices you can use:

```
for time in times:
    slice = df[df.mydate.dt.time < time]
    print(time, slice, sep='\n')
>>>
10:15:00
   col1              mydate
0     1 2016-12-25 09:15:00
11:15:00
   col1              mydate
0     1 2016-12-25 09:15:00
12:15:00
   col1              mydate
0     1 2016-12-25 09:15:00
1     2 2016-12-25 11:15:00
2     3 2016-12-26 11:15:00
13:15:00
   col1              mydate
0     1 2016-12-25 09:15:00
1     2 2016-12-25 11:15:00
2     3 2016-12-26 11:15:00
3     2 2016-12-26 12:15:00
```

Note how what you get are not actually slices, because they have overlapping records, so you might want to use something similar to:

```
for start, end in zip(times, times[1:]):
    slice = df[(start <= df.mydate.dt.time) & (df.mydate.dt.time <= end)]
```

As a final note, what you are trying to accomplish with the for loop can be obtained using the [group by](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) operations from pandas. You just need to prepare a `mytime` column with the times only:

```
df['mytime'] = df.mydate.dt.time
groups = df.groupby('mytime')

for group_key, group_df in groups:
    print(group_key, group_df, sep='\n')
>>>
09:15:00
   col1              mydate    mytime
0     1 2016-12-25 09:15:00  09:15:00
11:15:00
   col1              mydate    mytime
1     2 2016-12-25 11:15:00  11:15:00
2     3 2016-12-26 11:15:00  11:15:00
12:15:00
   col1              mydate    mytime
3     2 2016-12-26 12:15:00  12:15:00
```

The nice thing is that you don't need to operate on the single dataframes, but you can apply the same operations and aggregations on every group at the same time:

```
groups.size()
>>>
mytime
09:15:00    1
11:15:00    2
12:15:00    1

groups.sum()
>>>
          col1
mytime        
09:15:00     1
11:15:00     5
12:15:00     2
```