# Pandas count column a if column b condition

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe with two columns as shown below.

```
location   date
paris       6    
paris       4    
rome        3    
paris       5    
paris       6    
rome        6    
paris       4
```

Now I would like to have counted the different areas in column a, if column b is equal to 6.
So the desired result would be:

Paris 2

Rome 1

I am a total noob tbh, the basic idea would be: If column "date" is 6, count the values in column location.

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your dataframe is `df`:

```
df[df['date'] == 6]['location'].value_counts()
```

Will give you your desired result:

```
paris    2
rome     1
Name: location, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. Additionally, could you tell me how this would work if the values in column date would be e.g. "a" and "b", so non numerical?

Comment: @skzy Sure, in that case you would just change the == comparator, for example `df['date'] == 'a'` would work.

Answer (score 1):

It would be something like:

```
df[df['date']==6].groupby('location').count()
```

The `df[df['date']==6]` part, filters your DataFrame to only include rows with date values equal to 6. `groupby('location')` group filtered DataFrame by location value and `count()` counts the number of rows in groups.

Comment: Cool, this also works. Do you have an idea how to do the exact same if column date would instead be the time? The format is like this: 19:23:07. Let's say I want to count all the locations if the time is earlier than 18:00:00.

Comment: There is a good discussion about time columns in [compare a datetime column only to time in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561213/compare-a-datetime-column-only-to-time-in-pandas) but in a word you can first use `df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%H:%M:%S')` then filter your DataFrame by `df[df['date']<'18:00:00']`.